# GET response - Do NOT send a downlaodable file

Tags: python, http, request, tornado

My server in Python (Tornado) send a csv content on a GET request.

I want to specify the content type of the response as "text/csv", but when I do this the file is downlaoded when I send the GET request on my browser.

How can I specify the header "Content-type : text/csv" without having making it a downlaodable file but just show the content on my browser ?

Comment: Why do you want to send it as text/csv if you just want to show it in the browser? Why not just text/plain?

Comment: What your browser tries to do with a given content-type do not depends on the content-type but on the browser. You just have to configure your browser to display `text/csv` content type responses content instead of downloading them.

Comment: I have to put the content type as text/csv for my client.   @brunodesthuilliers Actually Im not able to find where can I change this setting in chrome or any browser ?

Answer (score 2):

The content-type header is what tells the browser how to display a given file. It doesn't know how to display `text/csv`, so it has no choice but to treat it as an opaque download. If you want the file to be displayed as plain text, you need to tell the browser that it has content-type `text/plain`.

If you need to tell other clients that the content type is `text/csv`, you need some way to distinguish clients that understand that content type from those that do not. The best way to do this is with the `Accept` request header. Clients that understand CSV would send `Accept: text/csv` in their request, and then the server would respond with content-type `text/plain` or `text/csv` depending on whether CSV appears in the accept header.

Using the `Accept` header may require modifications to the client, which may or may not be possible for you. If you can't update the clients to send the `Accept` header, then you'll have to use a hackier workaround. You can either use a different url (add `?type=plain` or `?type=csv`) or try to detect browsers based on their user agent.

Comment: Thanks for your complete response, this is very usefull.